# pine script trading - Partial exit working for long but not for short strategy

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

Hello and thank you for looking into this!

I have coded a pullback strategy, which attempts to buy once price retraces back to an EMA and then sells part of the position at a fixed ATR target, the other part at the next one, or at a raised stop. This works fine for exiting a long position. You can find the code I use below

```
if long_entry
    strategy.entry("buy", true, initial_qty , comment = "ELP")

strategy.exit("TP1", "buy", qty_tp1, limit = target_price1, stop = stop_price1)
strategy.exit("TP2", "buy", limit = target_price2, stop = stop_price1, when = strategy.position_size > qty_tp1 )
strategy.exit("TP2", "buy", limit = target_price2, stop = stop_price2, when = strategy.position_size < qty_tp1)
```

I I try to do the same for a variation of the strategy, that looks for shorts, the second stop will not trigger and no matter how I try to arrange things, will not work.

This is the short version

```
if short_entry
    strategy.entry("enter short", false, qty1, comment = "ESP")

strategy.exit("Stop1/TP1", "enter short", qty2, limit = target_price1, stop = stop_price1)
strategy.exit("Stop1/TP2", "enter short", limit = target_price2, stop = stop_price1, when = strategy.position_size < qty2)
strategy.exit("Stop2/TP2", "enter short", limit = target_price2, stop = stop_price2, when = strategy.position_size > qty2)
```

To make it easier to understand the approach, I have included two screenshots.

The [1st](https://www.tradingview.com/x/nxzZDwwv/) one shows how the raised stop triggers after price has reach TP1 in my long strategy. Red is the initial stop, blue the entry price, green the 1st and 2nd target and yellow the raised stop.

The [2nd](https://www.tradingview.com/x/3ArMMGYB/) one shows how the stop is unaffected by price trading through it.

I have tried all kinds of combinations with the "when" function, but I cannot get it to work. What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe the sort version fails because the strategy.position_size returns negative value for short position ( https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_strategy{dot}position_size )?

Comment: Yeah I though about that too. But no matter how I alter it, also with inserting the float * (-1) I cannot get it to work.

Comment: If you add full script version demonstrating the problem, I will could look.